# Magento2 How to add custom js for checkout billing address only

Tags: magento2, checkout, jquery, billing-address

Does anyone know how i can add custom js for billing address form only ?

i need to get default selected country from billing address

Comment: Do you want to add it on billing form or that page? And actual which task you need to perform on that one?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya  i want to get default selected country from billing address form

Comment: When do you want to add the custom js? when the payment step is loaded or when the billing address form is created? please explain a bit

Comment: @InvigorateSystems i want to add after billing address is created